# Perl download from url to local drive

Tags: perl, file, download

I want to offer my visitors a file for download to their local machine (e.g. the Download directory in case of Windows7).
The code below works perfectly well, but only if the file is located on the same machine as the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $path = "samples/10000.mp3"; ##PATH_TO_FILE
my $file = "10000.mp3";

print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name=\"$file\"\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"\r\n\n";

open( FILE, $path );

while(read(FILE, $buffer, 100) ){
print("$buffer");
}
```

The problem is that the file in question is located on another machine, so I have to get the url for download. I thought the coding below would do the trick, but no matter what I try, I end up with a downloaded file of 0 bytes. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;
my $url = 'http://<sampleurl>.com';
my $file = '10000.mp3';

my $path = get($url);

print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name=\"$file\"\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"\r\n\n";

open my $fh, '+>', $path;
while(read($fh, $buffer, 100) ){
print("$buffer");
}
```

Comment: LWP::Simple::get returns the document.  Why are you trying to open it as a file?  Does sampleurl.com really point you to files already on your server?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the sample url more realistic. It would be something like <sampleurl>.com/10000.mp3. I am trying to open it as a file so that it fits the coding of the first example since the first example works well(but only with a filepath, not with a url).

Comment: So you want to do `my $data = get("$url/$file")` and then `$print $data`, don't you?

Comment: But it's not like the first one, because there's no file to read from.

Answer (score 2):

The [`get` method in LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#get) returns the content, not the path to a file containing the content.

Once you have the content bits, write them to the standard output along with the header. Change your second program to

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://<sampleurl>.com';
my $file = '10000.mp3';

my $bits = get($url);
die "$0: get $url failed" unless defined $bits;

binmode STDOUT or die "$0: binmode: $!";

print qq[Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name="$file"\r\n],
      qq[Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$file"\r\n],
      qq[\r\n],
      $bits;
```

Comment: Thanks, Greg. This works. There is, however a downside. The "Do you want to open or save..." dialog doesn't appear until the whole file is read, which is a lot of hourglass time for the user. Is there a way to make it appear first? In case of my first sample, the dialog box appears first, and then the ...% download starts.